# AngularJS - $http service list objects by parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm sending this parameter *(year)* from a select element and I'm using the $http service in order to list an array of objects based on the parameter but for some reason it does not work.

> I have the **404 (Not Found)** error because the parameter does not
>   appear in the url in order to make the request.

**Select element:**

```
<select data-ng-model="year" data-ng-change="listByYear(year)">
    <option value="">Select year</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

**Controller *appController* and fuction *listByYear()*:**

```
moduleApp.controller("appController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.listByYear = function(year){
        console.info("Parameter received: "+year)
        var parameter = {
            year: $scope.year
        };
        var config = {
            param: parameter
        };
        $http.get("/pro/users/listByYear", config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.users = data;
            console.info("Ok")
        }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            console.error("Error")  
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: What is the url you want to receive from your back end?

Comment: Simply "pro/users/listByYear/2015" and the server will send all objects based in this parameter but when I see the console log in the browser I have an error with the following format "pro/users/listByYear/?year=2015" 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, this will do it (a simple string concatenation) :

```
$http.get('/pro/users/listbyyear/' + year);
```

will produce :

```
'/pro/users/listbyyear/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc I read `params` with an 's'.

So like this it should work better:

```
var config = {
    params: parameter
};
```

EDIT2:

You should use the standard 'then' method instead of 'success' and 'error' method because of the depreciation of these methods:

```
$http.get("/pro/users/listByYear", config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('data:', response.data);
        console.log('status:', response.status);
        console.log('headers:', response.headers);
    }).catch(function (response) {
        console.log('data:', response.data);
        console.log('status:', response.status);
        console.log('headers:', response.headers);
    });
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice